# Soft KeyBoard does not show up in Landscape orientation

Tags: java, android, landscape, portrait, nexus-5

In my app, I have a dialog with EditText. I have coded it in such a way that as soon as the dialog shows up,the soft keyboard shows up, the edit text will get focus , all the existing text in the editText is preselected. And user can start typing. This all works fine when I am holding my phone in portrait orientation. But the same thing does not work when I have phone in landscape orientation. Part of my code in my fragment is pasted below.

```
final EditText inputDeviceId = new EditText(getActivity());
inputDeviceId.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
String savedDevId = getDeviceID();
inputDeviceId.setText(savedDevId);
inputDeviceId.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

// some more code ... to create dialog , ok cancel buttons then,
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
inputDeviceId.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {       
    if(hasFocus){   
        alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

Now this all works in portrait orientation and does not work in landscape.
In landscape mode the dialog with edittext shows up , it has focus and existing text  is preselected but it does not show the keyboard. User has to click in the editText for keyboard to come up. Why? I am using nexus-5 to test.